# How do I enable Proxy Configuration File for VPN on Mac Terminal?

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, vpn, proxy

I'm using a Mac, I have the corporate VPN turned on (Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client)

In the Proxies tab of System Preferences I have "Proxy Configuration File" enabled with the URL (http://proxyaddress:portnumber)

I can connect to the internet via chrome browser fine, but my terminal has no internet access.

Is there a way for me to declare the Proxy Configuration File URL in Terminal, so I can connect terminal to the internet while the VPN is turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can’t.

Terminal is not a “network connected” application.  It is nothing more than a portal into the OS that allows you to enter and execute  commands. It’s the command(s) themselves that need to be able to utilize a proxy.

For example, you can’t `ping` or `traceroute` through a proxy; those commands will fail.  However, `curl` has the ability to specify a proxy with the flag `—-proxy <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]>`